# Parts of if statement not being exectued

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, 3d

I am using the Zdog library to create 3d objects in javascript. In the function that controls my animations I am trying to have a particle move around randomly and then after an interval return back to its original point. Here is my code:

```
if (radioOn == true){
  radio.zoom = size;
  path = [Math.floor((Math.random() * 3 - 1)),Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)),Math.floor((Math.random() * 2 - 1))];
  origin[0] += path[0];
  origin[1] += path[1];
  origin[2] += path[2];
  lightning.translate.x += path[0];
  lightning.translate.y -= path[1];
  lightning.translate.z += path[2];
  timer++;
  }
if (timer == 20){
  timer = 0;
  lightning.translate.x -= origin[0];
  lightning.translate.y += origin[1];
  lightning.translate.z -= origin[2];
  origin = [0,0,0];
}
```

I have put alerts in the second if statement and timer is getting reset but origin is not. Also the particle initially does what I need but after it gets reset it will no longer move.

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the browser console? What you describe sounds to me like there might be an error being thrown by some of the `lightning.x...` lines. What is `lightning` anyway?

Comment: @RobinZigmond There is no error which is why I am confused. Lightning is the object that contains all the info about the particle I am creating using the Zdog library.